# Can I create an "unsafe closure"?

Tags: rust, closures, unsafe

I have some code that, when simplified, looks like:

```
fn foo() -> Vec<u8> {
    unsafe {
        unsafe_iterator().map(|n| wrap_element(n)).collect()
    }
}
```

The iterator returns items that would be invalidated if the underlying data changed. Sadly, I'm unable to rely on the normal Rust mechanism of `mut` here (I'm doing some... odd things).

To rectify the unsafe-ness, I traverse the iterator all at once and make copies of each item (via `wrap_element`) and then throw it all into a `Vec`. This works because nothing else has a chance to come in and modify the underlying data.

The code works as-is now, but since I use this idiom a few times, I wanted to DRY up my code a bit:

```
fn zap<F>(f: F) -> Vec<u8>
    where F: FnOnce() -> UnsafeIter
{
    f().map(|n| wrap_element(n)).collect()
}

fn foo() -> Vec<u8> {
    zap(|| unsafe { unsafe_iterator() }) // Unsafe block
}
```

My problem with this solution is that the call to `unsafe_iterator` is unsafe, and it's the `wrap_element` / `collect` that makes it safe again. The way that the code is structured does not convey that at all.

I'd like to somehow mark my closure as being `unsafe` and then it's `zap`s responsibility to make it safe again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to create an `unsafe` closure in the same vein as an `unsafe fn`, since closures are just anonymous types with implementations of the `Fn`, `FnMut`, and/or `FnOnce` family of traits. Since those traits do not have `unsafe` methods, it's not possible to create a closure which is `unsafe` to call.

You could create a second set of closure traits with `unsafe` methods, then write implementations for those, but you would lose much of the closure sugar.

Comment: Creating a new set of traits is an interesting idea! I assume the sugaring is pretty tied to the compiler, and that there's nothing I can do as an end user to steal it for new traits?

Comment: You might be able to do something like blanket implement the new traits for the old traits, then you'd get implicit "conversion" from closure syntax to the unsafe traits. You still won't get the functional call syntax, but that's a fine tradeoff I think.

Comment: [I gave that a shot](http://is.gd/OgyWaO), but it's not as useful as it could have been. The problem is that the compiler still complains when we "call" the unsafe fn in the closure, because it doesn't know that the `unsafe` will be passed through, so there's no chance of using the sugar.